# Active MQ Transport Connector and Hostname

Tags: connection, activemq-classic, transport

I deployed Apache Active MQ on my Mac and the Transport connector is as follows.

```
 <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://localhost:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

However, I would like to replace "localhost" by a hostname that I specified in my /etc/hosts. I therefore modified my Transport Connector as follows:

After doing so, I have the following message when starting the broker:

```
Connecting to JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
INFO: Broker not available at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

Obviously, there is a JMX configuration that needs to be done ... but where? There is nothing related to JMX in conf/activemq.xml

Thanks for your help.
Christian

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveMQ installation folder contains a bin dir where there is a file named "env" which has configuration for the JMX endpoints on the JVM that is started to house the broker.  You can also place some user specific files in separate locations to control this.  There is some [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script) on this subject on the ActiveMQ website.

Comment: Thanks. What do I need to do to replace "0.0.0.0" (or localhost) by a hostname that I specified in my /etc/hosts in my transportConnector, and still get it working (I did the changes ans had the broker not available message)?